# Is it possible to use launch image for universal app in imageview of launchsceen.xib or launchscreen.storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, launch-screen, uiviewcontentmode

I have to use launch images in `imageview` of launch storyboard. But it's not supporting all orientations, and if I do `scaleToFill` in `contentmode` of `imageview`, then the image looks stretched. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Use autolayout and size classes

Comment: I am using autolayout and size classes. I set image to imageview from imageasset but either it takes proper image for landscape or portrait not for both.

Comment: Do u have separate launch image for Landscape and Portraint?

Comment: Yes separate launch images are being used for Landscape and Portrait mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `LaunchImage` directly, then the launch xib's wont load. If you want to load a xib with custom image for different orientation, then you have to add separate images in the asset catalogue.

Select the size classes for the image and use appropriate images.

[image]

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have done exactly same but its not picking correct image for iPad orientations.

Comment: For all the iPad orientations, the size class will be same. Regular-Regular. So it will load the same image.